# How To Include a Reversed Angle Symbol (⦣) in LaTeX

Tags: unicode

I am creating a LaTeX document in Overleaf, and I need to include the reversed angle character, "⦣", as well as a few other symbols that LaTeX does not recognize.

Is there a way to include the ⦣ symbol (or something that looks nearly identical) in my document?

And is there an easy, general way to include other unknown unicode symbols in LaTeX? Or is each character need to be included via a case-by-case basis?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the symbol in latex if you have a font for it, for example if you are using `unicode-math` it is available as `⦣` or `\revangle` and if you are using pdflatex you could use the `stix` package which again uses the commandname `\revangle`

[image]

with lualatex or xelatex :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\begin{document}

$a ⦣ b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello! How would I use `unicode-math` in my doc? It seems like I cannot import it as a package.

Comment: @diligar I added an example above you need lualatex or xelatex for unicode-math (or you can use the stix package with pdflatex)

Comment: The `stix` package did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `reflectbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\providecommand*{\revangle}{\reflectbox{$\angle$}}

\begin{document}

$a \angle b$

$a \revangle b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution worked, but the other one did not require a new command---thank you though!